# WordPress get_pages() within get_pages() loop?

Tags: wordpress

My theme is doing a one-page design and i have to output subpages in a nested way. So i thought i simply can use get_pages() two times like that:

```
<?php 
    $posts = get_pages(array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'parent' => 0,
    ));
    $i = 0; foreach($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
?>

<div class="center">

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php
        $children = get_pages(array(
            'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
            'parent' => $post->ID,
        ));
        foreach($children as $child): setup_postdata($child);
    ?>
        <div class="slide">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>

<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

It doesn't seem to be that easy though. The second the_title() doesn't work properly. It always outputs the title of the parent page.

How has something like this to be done correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setup_postdata()` requires a `$post` variable:

```
foreach($children as $post): setup_postdata($post);
```

Comment: you are right! that's weird. so the $post from the foreach loop overwrites the global $post and the_title() uses that? thank you!

Comment: the strange thing is that the_content() also worked with the variable name $child. :) that's why i am so confused.

Comment: You should also use wp_reset_postdata(); 

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata#Example_1

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options as far as i can see.

Option 1: Do it the right way by adding `hierarchical` to your first query and remove the second query.

Option 2: add `wp_reset_query();` underneath your first instance of `the_content();`

I hope this helps?

Comment: No, wp_reset_query() unfortunately had no effect. And hierarchical is 1 by default anyway. But I think hierarchical just affects the ordering. But I need that the parent wraps all its children with a <div> so I have to do this manually somehow i guess?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        $my_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_type' => 'page',
        ));
        if($my_query->have_posts())
        { 
            while($my_query->have_posts())
            {
                $my_query->the_post();
                ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php
            }
        }
        #wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

With WP_Query for the second query it works. I guess with get_pages() there just is a conflict with the internally used variables that get overwritten somehow?

Comment: `the_title()` is designed to be used in [`The Loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Fortunately WP is clever enough to recover the Title of the last `WP_Post` object that was created, I.e. the last in your loop (Pages, Posts and custom Post types are all returned as type `WP_Post`). By using `WP_Query` and `The Loop`, WP is correctly incrementing through your pages and giving you the correct title. Note that in the code given in your question, using `$child->post_title` would have worked fine.

Comment: thanks! yes, i noticed that $child->post_title worked fine. but i tried to be consistent and use the the_ functions since i thought maybe some filters could be configured. but now it came to my mind that the filters could be called manually too... so many possibilities. :)